# NPE on ResourceLink to global JNDI resource in tomcat 7.0.62

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jndi

I have a GlobalNamingResource in tomcat-7.0.62\conf\server.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/postgresDB"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/someDB"
        username="someUser"
        password="somePassword"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

and a Host configuration:

```
<Host name="localhost" deployXML="false">
```

In tomcat-7.0.62\conf\context.xml I have a ResourceLink to the global JNDI resource:

```
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/postgresDB" name="jdbc/postgresDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

When starting tomcat I get the following exception:

```
jaan 04, 2017 2:35:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetNextNamingRule.end(SetNextNamingRule.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1060)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    ...
jaan 04, 2017 2:35:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processContextConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in context.xml for /host-manager
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: .../apache-tomcat-7.0.62/conf/context.xml; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 69; Error at (25, 69) : null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2737)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1063)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
    ...
```

The `lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 69;` is directly at the end of ResourceLink tag in context.xml.

Playing around with the configuration I managed to get rid of the exception by removing the deployXML="false" attribute from server.xml Host tag. Same setup previously worked on tomcat 7.0.42.

What I do not understand is why it does not work in 7.0.62 and how am I supposed to do this in 7.0.62 if I want the deployXML attribute to be false. 
How exactly should I define ResourceLinks (like in this example the database connection) to share Resources across multiple webapps in the same tomcat instance.

Comment: In my config I haven't specified the factory in the server.xml, but my ResourceLink look exactly the same as yours.

Comment: @ChrisM the factory doesn't matter for the problem. It's actually the default so yes, I could leave it out completely. As I mentioned the `deployXML` attribute for the host seems to be the culprit.